# rpmlint: "W: no-version-in-last-changelog"

Tags: rpm-spec, changelog

When building RPMs in SLES12, I use `rpmlint` to check the spec files and packages.
I always get the warning `W: no-version-in-last-changelog`, but I cannot explain it:

The last lines of my `%changelog` reads like

```text
* Tue Jul 11 2011 My Self <my.email@address.here>
- Release 5.2.5-0.0: Initial release.
```

So I guess that's the "last" changelog the warning refers to, and there's clearly a version in it.
Even if it would refer to the first (latest) version, it wouldn't make a difference, as it looks very much the same:

```text
%changelog
* Thu Apr  8 2021 My Self <my.email@address.here>
- Release 5.28.0-0.0: Updated to...
  more text.

* Thu Jul 5 2018 ...next entry using just the same format...
```

Comment: Does your name have non-Latin characters? https://github.com/openSUSE/rpmlint-checks/issues/37

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco No, it has not.

Comment: Sorry; I got nothing then...

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at OpenSUSE RPM packaging guidelines on creating the changes file... https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Creating_a_changes_file_(RPM)

They suggest using the following format...

```
Tue Apr 22 20:54:26 UTC 2013 - your@email.com - x.y.z

- Update to new upstream release x.y.z:
  * bling and changes from upstream for that version
  * just the relevant parts, no info about other OS
  * and keep it as short as possible
```

So I think it's complaining because you ought to use format which looks something like this...

```
* Tue Jul 11 2011 My Self <my.email@address.here> - 5.2.5-0.0
- Initial release.
```

I'm pretty sure that you could also use the following if it's important to have the version number on the first line of the changes.

```
* Tue Jul 11 2011 My Self <my.email@address.here>
- 5.2.5-0.0
- Initial release.
```

Comment: But (for example) [Find the changelog / security log of a Linux rpm package](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-find-out-linux-rpm-package-changelog.html) and https://rpm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rpm-guide.html are using the "opposite format".

Comment: True but we're talking about the SUSE now. They do things differently and often in their own terms. Can you try out changing the format and see if SLES's rpmlint will accept it? Also the version number used in the latest change log entry should match the version and release of the package itself too.

Comment: I'm guessing that your issue is that the version number isn't the first thing following the name and email or it isn't in the same format as the package version and release. Also isn't this demonstrated as well in your links that the version and release number should follow the name and email from what I can tell?